# Django form widget does not display error

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a model.py:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    Author= models.CharField(max_length=500) ##field required
```

and a form.py:

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        widgets = {
            'Author': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Author...'}),
```

in template I render whit:

```
{{ form.Author }}
```

Form works but if I try to save leave the field empty it not display any error.

I try with

```
{{ form.Author.errors }}
```

but nothing appear!

Any idea?

TY

Comment: Can you add the relevant template code to the question please?

Comment: What does your view looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

UPGRADE 1

simple view:

```
@login_required 
def auth_reg(request): 
   if request.method == "POST": 
      form = AuthorForm(request.POST) 
      if form.is_valid(): 
         member = form.save() 
         return redirect('home') 
   else: form = AuthorForm() 
return render(request, auth_reg.html', {'form': form})
```

and simple template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div id="page-content-wrapper">

<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

   <div id="page-title">
      <h2>Registration</h2>
   </div>

   <div class="content-box-wrapper">
      <div class="form-horizontal bordered-row">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Author</label>
               <div class="col-sm-3">
                   {{ form.Author}}
               </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you mean to answer your own question?  Or was this meant to be an update?

Comment: upgrade as request

Comment: I presume you have to loop over the form errors in your template, like in this example https://gist.github.com/adamghill/8246816